# Refresh viewForFooterInSection on didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate

Tags: iphone, uitableview, footer

I am showing list of items on UITableViewCell in different sections. I have created UITextField in viewForFooterInSection delegate

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Now my problem is i dont want to show viewForFooterInSection everytime. It should be nil/hidden until i click didSelectRowAtIndexPath for that particular section. And UITextField should show only for that section only.

I am confused how to reload footerView on click ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reload the footer view simply by reloading the section.

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

After this call, `- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section` hits again, where you can keep a boolean variable and accordingly return nil or your footer view.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(conditionSatisfied)
        return myFooterView;
    return nil;
}
```

HTH,

Akshay

Comment: Reloading the section clobbers any other animation you might have been doing otherwise. I haven't seen any indication that this exists, but a reloadSectionFooter method would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is simply to call `[tableView reloadData]`.  Although this doesn't supply any sort of animation, I can't think of any nominally easy way to support animation in this case.  It may be possible by inserting a row at the bottom of the section that looks like the footer, but that comes with another whole host of issues that I wouldn't want to deal with.

**Edit**: Just found a possibly slightly better option:

`[tableView reloadSections:withRowAnimation:]`.  I've no idea whether this will animate the footer or not, or whether it will even make the query to your data provider, but it's worth a shot.